# URL syntax checking annoyance in C++ comments

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

In the Visual Studio 2013 editor, the following URL syntax works in C/C++ comment blocks - for single click navigation:

```
//
// http://bitbucket.org/foo/main.cpp#cl-123
//
```

The Visual Studio 2015 editor considers the fragment starting with # not to be part the URL. It does accept %23 instead of # but the server does not like it:

```
//
// http://bitbucket.org/foo/main.cpp%23cl-123
//
```

Is there a way to relax the URL encoding / syntax checking in VS 2015?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Surround the offending URL with " " ( ) or { }.